# Selecting multiple radio buttons

Tags: custom-fields

Could anyone tell me how I can set up a customised field which allows me to select multiple options in each field?

Do you know if it's then possible to generate reports which show all records with a selected group of checkboxes checked for a specific custom field?

Comment: Do you mean checkboxes? By definition radios only allow single choice.

Comment: Yes, I guess checkboxes might be it.  Do you know if it's then possible to generate reports which show all records with a selected group of checkboxes checked for a specific custom field?

Comment: Yes it is. Check out the public demo at demo.civicrm.org. I just tried it and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Setting up your custom checkbox field is fairly simple. See the chapter on [Creating Custom Fields](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/).

Yes you can create reports that filter based on multiple values in a custom field:

[image]